# Airflow: Unable to create view using Bigquery hooks

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

I am trying to create bigquery view in airflow using bigquery hook and is giving me the following error. Please find the code snippet below:

```
BigQueryHook().create_empty_table(
                        dataset_id="data_loader_view",
                        table_id="customerdata",
                        view={
                            "query": "SELECT * FROM data_loader.customerdata",
                            "useLegacySql": False
                            }
                        )
```

Traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 930, in _run_raw_tas
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execut
    return_value = self.execute_callable(
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 118, in execute_callabl
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/bigquery_view_dag.py", line 37, in create_bq_vie
    view_util.create_bq_view_util(context['final_dict']
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/utils/view.py", line 29, in create_bq_view_uti
    "useLegacySql": Fals
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/providers/google/common/hooks/base_google.py", line 356, in inner_wrappe
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/bigquery.py", line 339, in create_empty_tabl
    retry=retr
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 544, in create_tabl
    retry, method="POST", path=path, data=data, timeout=timeou
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 556, in _call_ap
    return call(
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 286, in retry_wrapped_fun
    on_error=on_error
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 184, in retry_targe
    return target(
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line 423, in api_reques
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<project_name>/datasets/data_loader_view/tables: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "query" at 'table.view': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list
[2020-10-01 04:25:30,857] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 53554: Subtask create_bq_view [2020-10-01 04:25:30,612] {taskinstance.py:1059} ERROR - 400 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<project_name>/datasets/data_loader_view/tables: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "query" at 'table.view': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list.
```

Referred documentation:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/hooks/bigquery_hook/index.html#airflow.contrib.hooks.bigquery_hook.BigQueryBaseCursor.create_empty_table

Please help me solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the code below as an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks import bigquery
from airflow.operators import python_operator
from airflow import models
import datetime

#Creating function that calls the view creation
def create_view(ds, **kwargs):
    bigquery.BigQueryHook().create_empty_table(dataset_id='<my-dataset>',
            table_id='customerdata',
            view={'query': 'SELECT * FROM `<my-dataset>.<my-source-table>`',
            'useLegacySql': False})


default_dag_args = {
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 2, 11, 5),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=1),
    'project_id': '<my-project-id>',
    }

with models.DAG('bigquery_airflow', schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *',
                default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:
    create_view = python_operator.PythonOperator(task_id='succeeded',
            provide_context=True, python_callable=create_view)

    create_view
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add your actual project name in your code?

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/**<project_name>**/datasets/data_loader_view/tables
```

Also, from the documentation you provided, this part contains the Project ID as opposed to your code which only contains two components (`data_loader.customerdata`)

```
view = {
"query": "SELECT * FROM `**test-project-id**.test_dataset_id.test_table_prefix*` LIMIT 1000",
"useLegacySql": False
```

}

Comment: I have added the project id in the query & in the code. I don't work.